# How should I call loaded Localization json data in second dart file?

Tags: json, localization, dart, flutter

I have a 3 JSON files under lib/resources/lang/. I also have demo_localizations.dart (based on: https://github.com/anilcancakir/flutter-internationalization) file under lib/. I also have a second_page.dart under lib/drawer. When I call second_page.dart I don’t get any localization on the second page.

The en, ru, and tr JSON file example:

```
{ "greetings": "Hello world", "secondPageTitle": "Second Page" }
{ "greetings": "Привет мир", "secondPageTitle": "Вторая страница"}
{ "greetings": “Merhaba Dünya”, "secondPageTitle": “Sayfa İki“}
```

This is the part of the main page localisation as:
new Text(DemoLocalizations.of(context).trans('greetings’)),

**And this is my second_page.dart code:**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../demo_localizations.dart';

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _SecondPageState createState() => new _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
                title: new Text('Second Page'),
            ),
            body: new Center(
                // TODO: This part is not working
                child: new Text(DemoLocalizations.of(context).trans('secondPageTitle')),

                // TODO: This is working without using DemoLocalizations
                //child:new Text('Second Page'),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

And this is my demo_localizations.dart code:

```
    import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';



class DemoLocalizations {
    DemoLocalizations(this.locale);

    final Locale locale;

    static DemoLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
        return Localizations.of<DemoLocalizations>(context, DemoLocalizations);
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> _sentences;

    Future<bool> load() async {
        String data = await rootBundle.loadString('resources/lang/${this.locale.languageCode}.json');
        this._sentences = json.decode(data);
        return true;
    }

    String trans(String key) {
        return this._sentences[key];
    }
}



class DemoLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<DemoLocalizations> {
    const DemoLocalizationsDelegate();

    @override
    bool isSupported(Locale locale) => ['tr', 'en', 'ru'].contains(locale.languageCode);

    @override
    Future<DemoLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
        DemoLocalizations localizations = new DemoLocalizations(locale);
        await localizations.load();

        print("Load ${locale.languageCode}");

        return localizations;
    }

    @override
    bool shouldReload(DemoLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
}
```

How should I call loaded Localization JSON data in the second dart file?

Comment: hi, i know it is an old question. But i recently wrote an Visual Studio Code extensions to cope with localization json files in flutter: https://github.com/esskar/vscode-flutter-i18n-json

Comment: I followed [this](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/internationalization---make-an-flutter-application-multi-lingual/) post and it worked pretty well! I'm not what you called an expert in Flutter/Dart, so cannot help with that specific code you showed! Hope that helps!